# How to reproduce php Crypt() in java for custom sha256 rounds

Tags: java, hash, cryptography

I have a php script that store `crypt()` results with a custom rounds off 10000 and some already existing salt.

The code look like that :

```
echo crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$5$rounds=10000$usesomesillystringforsalt$');
```

And the output is

> $5$rounds=10000$usesomesillystri$CaVZTpnmHfz9Fi6zjGJmSAAwwABsSqSJbtzdlfvVC10

Witch is not a hash in hexa nor in binary, it seem to be a Crypt3 output.

Question is "How to get this same string for the same input in Java ?"

For now all `MessageDigest` & SO answers tested don't work, as it print directly the hash in hexa (aka lot of pain to compare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally able to find a way to get the same output.

Using the Apache Commons `Crypt` I get the same output with the salt round and everything.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt;
return Crypt.crypt("rasmuslerdorf", "$5$rounds=10000$usesomesillystringforsalt$");
```

Will get me my :

> $5$rounds=10000$usesomesillystri$CaVZTpnmHfz9Fi6zjGJmSAAwwABsSqSJbtzdlfvVC10